# Why is destructor not called for private nested class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, nested, destructor, private

So this is my code in Car.h

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Car
{

private:
    int speed;
    class GearBox;
    GearBox& gearBox;

public:
    Car();
    ~Car();
};

class Car::GearBox {
private:
    int gear;

public:
    GearBox();
    ~GearBox();
};
```

In Car.cpp i have

```
#include"Car.h"


    Car::Car(): speed(0), gearBox(GearBox())
{
    cout << "Car constructor" << endl;

}


Car::~Car()
{
    cout << "Car destructor" << endl;
}

Car::GearBox::GearBox(): gear(0)
{
    cout << "Gearbox constructor" << endl;
}

Car::GearBox::~GearBox()
{
    cout << "GearBox destructor" << endl;
}
```

and my main is:

```
#include"Car.h"


int main() {

    {
        cout << "Starting program!" << endl;

        Car car;

    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Result of the program is:
Starting program!
GearBox constructor
Car constructor
Car destructor

Why is Gearbox destructor not outputted?
(it makes sense to me that car has a reference to his gearbox because gearbox should exist while car does exist)

Comment: Are you using MSVS?  If you are note that `gearBox(GearBox())` is illegal as you are binding a temporary to an lvalue reference.

Comment: That code isn't valid C++. Lvalue references do not bind to rvalues.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes i am using MSVS. Ok then why does program successfully compiled? And how can i get this right?

Comment: @Bunc I compiles because Microsoft decide to allow it to.  It is an evil extension that should be removed.  You can capture a temporary with a `const &` but you will not be able to modify it.

Comment: @NathanOliver i am sure that u know that if i type:
    GearBox gearBox;

it will say that incomplete type is not allowed. What is the solution?
(except to avoid nested classes maybee :D)

Comment: I used your code in VS2013. It works and the both destructors are called. I also got a warning - C4413. The destructor of Gear is called before the destructor of the Car, which seems normal. The car is having only a reference to the Gear.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this with VS2013.  You should verify that you've posted the actual code that is causing the problem for you.  If so, you may need to give more details about the toolchain version you're using and how you're building the program.

Comment: @Bunc: you can put the definition of `class GearBox` inside the definition of `class Car` (before you actually instantiate a `GearBox` member).  That will let you avoid having to use a `GearBox&`.

Comment: @lonel POP i have VS 2015.

Comment: @Michael Burr, all good, posted code is same as actual code!

Comment: I believe I reproduced this on VS 2015 (assuming that's is 19.0) using an online compiler (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

This would have to be a compiler bug, potentially related to the fact that it allows that reference initialisation in the first place (which is a Visual Studio extension, not compliant to any version of the actual, standardised, C++ language).

I believe I can reproduce this using an online VS compiler:

[image: Reproduction screenshot]

C++ compilers are allowed to elide copy operations even if they contain output like this, but not constructors and destructors.

Comment: @bunc: Yeah okay bug then. Try posting it on MS Connect

Comment: A responsible person for memory leak is not compiler but developer.

Comment: @nariuji: This is not a memory leak. Or, if it is, it's definitely the fault of the compiler. The program is well-formed so the developer has satisfied their responsibilities.

Comment: It is wrong that the member of reference variable retains temporary instance ordinary. That is a bug.
In the case reference variable is initialized in the constructor of parent class, where is a security of calling destructor of temporary class?

Comment: @nariuji: No, that's not a bug; it's a well-known Visual Studio extension. That the temporary's destructor is not invoked when the temporary goes out of scope, is a bug. Admittedly it's hard to call this non-compliant behaviour, when supporting the reference initialisation isn't compliant to begin with... but I'd say it's pretty obvious that failing to destroy an object is not intended behaviour of any compiler.

Comment: In the case of gcc, if it is a const member, that can be compiled.
Though, the lifetime of temporary object was supposed to be the same as the lifetime of const reference variable usually,
but it doesn't work out that way.
To substitute a temporary object for a reference variable member is an illegal operation.
Therefore I think it is not compulsory for a compiler to guarantee an illegal operation safety.
I believe that a programing is not a puzzle game.
As a programing design, is it a necessary that this variable is specified in a reference variable member?

Comment: Sorry, @nariuji, but once again I haven't the foggiest idea what you're talking about!

Comment: I think engineers shouldn't write a program in such a way as to induce the destruction of the stacks.
Because software development includes various phases like coding, designing and testing.

Comment: @nariuji: You're still not making any sense.

Comment: I think that a conclusion has been reached already from the beginning.

Answer (score -2):

Is GearBox instantiated?

```
Car::Car(): speed(0), gearBox(GearBox())
{
    cout << "Car constructor" << endl;
}
```

↓

`Car::Car(): speed(0)`
`{`
    `static GearBox inst;`
　　　 <del>gearBox = inst;</del>
    `cout << "Car constructor" << endl;`
`}`

**EDIT:**

```
class Car
{
private:
    int speed;
    class GearBox { // referable
    private:
        int gear;
    public:
        GearBox() : gear(0) {
            cout << "Gearbox constructor" << endl;
        }
        ~GearBox() {
            cout << "GearBox destructor" << endl;
        }
    };
    GearBox* gearBox;

public:
    Car();
    ~Car();
};

Car::Car(): speed(0)
{
    static GearBox inst;
    gearBox = &inst;
    cout << "Car constructor" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Even though it can be compiled, what is the point of not working code? :D